# Prove that: $(A-B)\cap B=\phi$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that: $(A-B)\cap B=\phi$.

My Attempt:

Let $x$ be an element of $(A-B)\cap B$. Then,
$$x\in (A-B)\cap B \iff x\in (A-B) \textrm {and} x\in B$$
$$\iff (x\in A \textrm {and} x\notin B) \textrm {and} x\in B$$.

Comment: $x \notin B \land x \in B$ gives you a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: $A-B=A\cap B'$ and $B'\cap B=\Phi$

Comment: @Su20200  over-complicating matters.

Comment: @KennyLau:  Yes, precisely, there is no element  that is in B and also not it B.

Comment: I'd use $\LaTeX$ `\emptyset` rather than `\phi`, so $\emptyset$ instead of $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. No element can be in both $B$ and $B^c$. Formally we can write, by definition of set subtraction,
\begin{align*}
A - B = A \cap B^c.
\end{align*}
Since $(A \cap B^c) \cap B$ is a subset of $B^c \cap B = \emptyset$, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right. Use three things:

1) $A-B=A\cap B'$

2) $B\cap B'=\Phi$

3) $A \cap \Phi = \Phi$